# How do I remove letters in an f-string after selecting the name of the table?

Tags: python, sql

Here is my code:

```
for tables in cursor.fetchall():
    tab = tables[0] 
    select_stg_query = f"""SELECT * from {tab}"""       
    try:
        df_select=pd.read_sql(select_stg_query, conn, chunksize=10000)
        warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
        continue  

    try:
        engine = sa.create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://@{target_server}/{target_database}?trusted_connection=yes&driver={target_driver}')

        for chunk_dataframe in df_select:
            rowcount = chunk_dataframe.to_sql(f'{tab}_BIC', engine, if_exists='append', index=False, method='multi', chunksize=10)
            warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
            print("{} Records inserted ".format(rowcount) + f"into {tab}_BIC")
            engine.dispose()
```

The tables I am selecting from have the prefix `"stg_"` in front of them. I want to remove that prefix when I am inserting records from those "stg_" tables into the new tables. I don't want the new tables to have "stg_" in the name. So every time I run this, I will have to have "stg_" in the front which I don't want. I tried doing this:

```
f'{tab}_BIC'.strip('stg_')
```

but it didn't do anything. I am inserting data from STG database to DW database and all the tables in STG have "stg_" in front of it and the DW tables are the same tables but I don't want "stg_" there.

Answer (score 1):

If all your tables have the same prefix `stg_`, you can use:

```
chunk_dataframe.to_sql(f'{tab.split("_", maxsplit=1)[-1]}_BIC', ...)
```

Note: this code `f'{tab}_BIC'.strip('stg_')` works for me.

```
# tab = 'stg_mytable'

>>> f'{tab}_BIC'.strip('stg_')
mytable_BIC

>>> f'{tab.split("_", maxsplit=1)[-1]}_BIC'
mytable_BIC
```